# Add current time to \today with package datetime? (LaTeX)

Tags: datetime, latex

I'm trying to  have my LaTeX articles print with both the current date and the time. I found a package called `datetime` which lets me redefine `\today` to a variety of formats. But it doesn't have an obvious way to modify `\today` to include the time, and the code is so twisted that I can't figure it out myself. Is there an easy way to do this?

### EDIT

I want to have the time automatically printed with the date on the front page when I run the `\maketitle` command. As by default, it executes in the hidden command `\date{\today}`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Nevermind my comment,
I found something that works without all the makeatletters

```
\usepackage{datetime}
%...
\title{This is the Title}
\author{An Author's name}
\date{\currenttime}
\maketitle
```

Comment: That's it!  Although I changed it to \date{\currenttime \today}

Comment: +1 In addition to @vy32's comment, to use the default date format for `\today` add `\usdate` before the `\date{...}` command.

Comment: `datetime` has recently been replaced with `datetime2`. See CTAN: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime2

Answer (score 10):

datetime package provides a `\currenttime` command. I would recommend using `\currenttime` directly instead of trying to modify/redefine `\today`.

Comment: The problem is, the `\maketitle` comamnd in the `article` format automatically prints `\today` on the title page. I want to print the time on the title page.

Comment: I tried something like this but this only shows the time. Maybe someone can help correcting that where it keeps everything else the same but changes the date command
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{
\currenttime{\@date}
}
\makeatother